# Cannon JS Collision detect amount of force

Tags: three.js, collision-detection, cannon.js

I have two Cannon.js Objects, and have attached the "collide" event listener to both.

```
carBody.addEventListener("collide",function(e){
});
```

I want to be able to react differently depending on how much force the collision has is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6):

You can get the relative velocity in the contact point to determine the amount of energy in the collision. Example:

```js
carBody.addEventListener("collide",function(e){
    var relativeVelocity = e.contact.getImpactVelocityAlongNormal();
    if(Math.abs(relativeVelocity) > 10){
        // More energy
    } else {
        // Less energy
    }
});
```